# Viewing video stream in Android - Uri is <URL suppressed>

Tags: android, url, streaming, uri, android-videoview

I am working on an app that i want to display video stream from my ip camera. 
I am getting this:
"Uri is URL suppressed, Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side". I tried with VideoView and with MediaPlayer and surface. I can get rtsp stream in VLC from my camera and i turned off authentification. On vlc it worked with provided rtsp url. If any of you guys can help me, i will be very thankfull. If it is a common knowledge and a lot of describing, please give me some source of information. Thank you!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final static String USERNAME = "admin";
final static String PASSWORD = "123456";
final static String RTSP_URL = "rtsp://192.168.1.158:554/";


private VideoView myVideoView;
private MediaController mediaControls;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (mediaControls == null){
        mediaControls = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
    }
    myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    myVideoView.setMediaController(mediaControls);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(RTSP_URL);
    myVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){


        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myVideoView.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see how to stream video from camera:

https://github.com/nessup/better-spydroid

https://github.com/fyhertz/spydroid-ipcamera

Comment: Please, before answering, read what i want to do. I'm looking for a way to recieve video stream from ip cam over rtsp.